# Making an app's updated version compatible with its previous versions

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, game-center

I am getting ready to release my first app to the iphone market. This app involves multilayer components.

In future updates I'm planning on adding a new character, board, and skin for the character.

I'm concerned that if I update the app (say release version 1.1) and one player (P1) is play on the updated version and the other player (P2) is playing on the previous version, the two players will run into problems. Even if the P1 (on version 1.1) is using something not included in version 1.0.

Would I have to add catchers for these problems in version 1.0? Would I have to make everyone play on the same version of the app? Or would it not really be an issue?

EDIT: I don't know if this is important but I'm running the connection through Apple's Game Center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to check during the connection if the versions of the app are the same. If they aren't, display a message to the player of the older one, and tell him to update. Also don't let him play if he doesn't updates. This will avoid many problems.

Comment: Thanks I think I'm going to do some variation of this anwser, let him play and verse his friend, just an older version of the game without all the newer functions.

Comment: Good, but try avoid making sad players with new versions because they can't play with new content.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on how you've create your app. In my head the easiest way would be to add catches in the beginning, so if something happens the app doesn't recognise, use some default behaviour. Another way would be to just limit to the same version of the app when playing each other.